# ros2 optionally launch node with no arguments

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node that takes zero or one argument.  I want to use ros2 launch arguments to pass either zero or one argument to the the launch file which will then get passed down to the node.  I'm having a bit of trouble with the 'zero' argument case.

```
LaunchDescription([
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "my_param",
        default_value=[""],  # default_value=[], has the same problem
        description="optional parameter"
    ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="my_package",
        node_executable="my_node",
        arguments=[launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration("my_param")]
    ),
])
```

When I do this, I can run my launch file with `my_param:=foo` and `foo` will get passed down to my node.  No problem

When I run my launch file without any arguments, my_node still behaves like it got a positional argument - a single empty string.  This is not how I intended to launch the node.

What do I need to do to make my_node behave like it got no arguments when I don't pass any arguments to launch?

The current behavior makes sense - the LaunchConfiguration substitution is getting resolved to an empty string and is getting put into the node's arguments array.  What I need is a way to substitute the whole 'arguments' list passed to the node instead of substituting a single element in the list, but the Node object really wants a list of substitutions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314903/ros2-optionally-launch-node-with-no-arguments/) by [Pete B](https://answers.ros.org/users/39471/pete-b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2019-02-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no way to do this (conditionally include a substitution in a list) right now.

You could do something like this:

```
LaunchDescription([
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "my_param",
        default_value=[""],  # default_value=[], has the same problem
        description="optional parameter"
    ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="my_package",
        node_executable="my_node",
        arguments=[launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration("my_param")],
        condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration("my_param")),
    ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="my_package",
        node_executable="my_node",
        arguments=[],
        condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration("my_param")),
    ),
])
```

Which is obviously silly, but it's the only way to express it at the moment.

As a long term solution, I think we either need conditional Substitutions, where maybe they return `None` if the condition is false, and code that processes lists of substitutions would ignore (just drop) any substitutions that return `None`, or some way to process lists of substitutions conditionally (not sure how that would work off hand).

Then you'd be able to do something like this:

```
LaunchDescription([
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "my_param",
        default_value=[""],  # default_value=[], has the same problem
        description="optional parameter"
    ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="my_package",
        node_executable="my_node",
        arguments=[launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration("my_param", condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration("my_param"))]
    ),
])
```

Or some short hand for self-evaluating the substitution, e.g.:

```
LaunchDescription([
    launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
        "my_param",
        default_value=[""],  # default_value=[], has the same problem
        description="optional parameter"
    ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package="my_package",
        node_executable="my_node",
        arguments=[launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration("my_param", condition=launch.conditions.UnlessEmpty())]
    ),
])
```

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mogumbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30569/mogumbo/) on 2019-07-16**:
Has there been any progress on this? I think I'm having the same problem. I have

```
gzserver = launch.actions.ExecuteProcess(
cmd=['gzserver', '--verbose', '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_init.so',
  LaunchConfiguration('command_arg1'),
  LaunchConfiguration('world_name')],
output='screen'
)
```

LaunchConfiguration('command_arg1' sometimes evaluates to '' and my launch script fails with [gzserver-1] [Err] [Server.cc:382] Could not open file[]

**Comment by [newellr](https://answers.ros.org/users/27470/newellr/) on 2019-07-26**:
I'm interested in this too. I've opened an issue on ros2/launch. https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/290